# Can Azure use PUT instead of PATCH for updating resoures via SCIM?

Tags: azure, provisioning, scim2

I'm trying to use SCIM for user account provisioning in Azure.  It looks like when a resource needs to be updated, PATCH is being used, but the SCIM endpoint doesn't support PATCH, only PUT requests.  Is there a way to configure Azure to use PUT instead of PATCH?

Answer (score 0):

There is not. Only PATCH is supported for updating resources via SCIM.